# Purple and white mix gradient

Tags: css

For a button gradient using CSS, how could I possibly combine #fff with a purple to achieve the white/purple background somewhat close to the edges in this image?

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the tool @Diodeus linked, I created a setup that you can tweak:

http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#a8a8a8+0,2300b2+100;Custom

Here it is in action:

http://jsfiddle.net/vCYUX/1/

Answer (score 0):

Use the [ColorZilla gradient generator](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/).

Comment: @Diodeus perhaps you could elaborate. I'm curious myself how to create such a complex gradient with ColorZilla (unless the OP actually means the radial gradient in the middle, which is pretty simple). Anyway, a short explanation would be nice, even for the heck of avoiding an automatic "low quality" flag.